# Uncaught TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to add firebase firestore to my web application so i used the this code

```
var firebaseConfig = {

  apiKey: "XXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  databaseURL: "XXX",
  projectId: "XXX",
  storageBucket: "XXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXX",
  appId: "XXX",
  measurementId: "XXX",
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

var db = firebase.firestore();
```

but it is giving me the error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function
```

this is what i linked to the html

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`firebase` core library does not include the `firestore` library, so you need to do the following imports:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Comment: it gave me this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module any ideas? thanks

Comment: If you're not using `import` yet, you don't need to add it for this problem. Importing the Firestore SDK with `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>` may be enough as shown in the second answer I linked to your question.

Comment: yeah linking <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script> worked thanks so much